# Div Random Positioning Without Overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a series of divs be randomly placed within another div, without overlap. I am having issues getting them to not overlap but can't seem to figure out why. I've attached the entire script to run, but I think the problem lies in the piece of code I left at the end.

```
<?php
$number_of_tags = 7;    // Number of tags in tag cloud, excluding search box
$tags = array();        // Initiate tags() array
$weight = array();      // Initiate weight() array

// This function generates random tags
// Not needed when fetching from database
function generate_tag() {
$tag_min_length = 5;
$tag_max_length = 30;

$letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for ($a = 0; $a <= rand($tag_min_length,$tag_max_length); $a++) {
       $b = rand(0, strlen($letters) - 1);
       $tag .= $letters[$b];
}
return $tag; 
}

for($i=0; $i<$number_of_tags;$i++){
$tags[$i][0] = generate_tag();
$tags[$i][1] = rand(10,22);     // Font size between 10 and 22, random. Replace with weight from database
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>smoketag</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<style>
    #tag_cloud {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 600px;
        height: 200px;

    }
    .tag {
        background: #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: left;
        margin: 3px;
        padding: 7px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
    .tag:hover {
        background: #aaa;
    }
    .searchbox {
        cursor: auto;
        width: 300px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tag_cloud">
<input class="tag searchbox" type="textbox">
<?php
    foreach($tags as $k=>$v){
        echo "<div class='tag alive' id='tag_".$k."' style='font-size:".$v[1]."px;'>".$v[0]."</div>";
    }
?>
</div>
<script>
var boundries = new Array();

function checkBoundries(tag_id){
var thisTag = $("#tag_"+tag_id);
var max_top = $("#tag_cloud").outerHeight() - thisTag.outerHeight(true);
var max_left = $("#tag_cloud").outerWidth() - thisTag.outerWidth(true);

// propose new location
var proposedTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt(max_top));
var proposedLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt(max_left));
var top = proposedTop;
var right = proposedLeft + thisTag.outerWidth(true);
var bottom = proposedTop + + thisTag.outerHeight(true);
var left = proposedLeft;
console.log("     "+top+"     ");
console.log(left+"       "+right);
console.log("     "+bottom+"     ");



// check curent tags for conflicts
var fullPass = true;
$(".tag").each(function(x){
    if(tag_id!=x){
        var c_top = parseInt(thisTag.css('top')); // Top
        var c_right = parseInt(thisTag.css('left'))  + thisTag.outerWidth(true);// Right
        var c_bottom = parseInt(thisTag.css('top')) + thisTag.outerHeight(true); // Bottom
        var c_left = parseInt(thisTag.css('left')); // Left
        var passed = true;
        var height_conflict = false;
        var width_conflict = false;
        if(((top<=c_bottom)&&(top>=c_top))||((bottom<=c_bottom)&&(bottom>=c_top))){ var height_conflict = true; }
        if(((right<=c_left)&&(right>=c_right))||((left>=c_left)&&(left<=c_right))){ var width_conflict = true; }
        //console.log(height_conflict + " " + width_conflict);
        if((height_conflict)&&(width_conflict)){ passed = false; }
        console.log(tag_id + ':' + x + " -- " + passed);
        if(passed==false){
            //checkBoundries(tag_id);
            fullPass = false;
            console.log("RESET");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
if(fullPass==true){
    // No conflicts. Move tag to new location
    //thisTag.css('top',Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt(max_top)));
    //thisTag.css('left',Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt(max_left)));
    thisTag.css({top: proposedTop+"px"});
    thisTag.css({left: proposedLeft+"px"});
    console.log('moving: ' + tag_id + " --- top: " + top + " --- left: " + left);
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
// Set textbox to center
$(".searchbox").css('top', (parseInt($("#tag_cloud").height())/2) - ($(".searchbox").height()/2)+"px");
$(".searchbox").css('left', (parseInt($("#tag_cloud").width())/2) - ($(".searchbox").width()/2)+"px");

// Start building
for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
    while(checkBoundries(i)==false){
        // do nothing
    }   
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the issue is with this logic:

```
if(((top<=c_bottom)&&(top>=c_top))||((bottom<=c_bottom)&&(bottom>=c_top))){ var height_conflict = true; }
if(((right<=c_left)&&(right>=c_right))||((left>=c_left)&&(left<=c_right))){ var width_conflict = true; }
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing that is bad?  Also, why do you hate whitespace?  What did it ever do to you?

Comment: I don't know why it's pasting in like that, it looks fine in my IDE.
What I'm seeing that is bad is that the divs are still overlapping.

Comment: But what does the code do that you don't want it to do?  Or what isn't it doing that you do want?

Comment: What it does is overlap them... What it isn't doing is not overlapping them.

Comment: Does it run forever?  You may have a problem where you can't ever get a valid position.  This is not a good approach to doing this.  You should store your open spaces in an array or something and then randomly select an open space.  This is like "guess my number from 1 to 1 million"  while rand() != my_number, try again.  It may never finish.

Comment: It finishes fine, and very quickly with so few elements in a area that is large enough to easily fit them all. The problem is that it won't recognize when it is overlapping, like I stated in my previous comments. I attached the whole code to the question so it can be run so whoever is looking at it can see it first hand.

Comment: so it goes over each existing tag and you see the line         console.log(tag_id + ':' + x + " -- " + passed);
and it says true each time?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6520/discussion-between-xaxxon-and-nick-barone)

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have a PHP system set up to run your code.

Comment: You can see what's going on here: http://nbar1.com/apps/smoke_tag/

Comment: This is why you should create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var c_top = parseInt(thisTag.css('top')); // Top
var c_right = parseInt(thisTag.css('left')) + thisTag.outerWidth(true);// Right
var c_bottom = parseInt(thisTag.css('top')) + thisTag.outerHeight(true); // Bottom
var c_left = parseInt(thisTag.css('left')); // Left
```

Your problem is here.  You're comparing the proposed location of each box against that same box's current location (which default to the top left) each time.  Because of this, as long as the proposed location isn't in the top left corner, it will always allow the position.  Instead of comparing to thisTag (which is the same tag you're trying to place each time), you want to compare against x, the iterator variable in your each() loop.

Comment: That was definitely an issue, however still did not solve the issue of the boxes overlapping.

Comment: Yeah, you have lots of problems.  You can't check to see if either the top or the bottom is between another box.  What if it completely covers it?  The top could be above the top and bottom below the bottom.